# Select count with two conditions in one alias

Tags: mysql

My sql table has the following structure:

`id, sender, recipient, content, date_sent, last_activity, sender_read, recipient read`

It is for personal messages. The `sender` row is the user's id that sent a message. When he receives a reply, `sender_read` becomes `1` and the same goes for `recipient`. I need to count the total of unread messages a user has. I tried something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN recipient = ? AND recipient_read = 0 THEN 1 END) as unread FROM pm 
UNION SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN sender = ? AND sender_read = 0 THEN 1 END) as unread FROM pm
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Basically I need to combine two counts and return one alias. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine the 2 conditions into a single case expression:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN recipient = ? AND recipient_read = 0 THEN 1
                  WHEN sender = ? AND sender_read = 0 THEN 1 
                  ELSE null
             END) as unread FROM pm 
WHERE recipient = ? OR sender = ?
```